# Why I am not getting any output here?

Tags: c

In project Euler there is a problem titled Smallest Multiple. I tried to solve it and try to write a code for that problem. But I didn't get any output!
The problem is described below:

**2520 is the smallest number that can be divided by each of the numbers from 1 to 10 without any remainder.
What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?**

So I write code for this problem. First of all I write a code to check whether it's correct or not that 2520 is the smallest number that can be divided by each of the numbers from 1 to 10 without any remainder. For that problem I write the below program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
  int i,j,count = 0,num;

  for (i = 1; count != 10; i++) {
    count = 0;

    for (j = 1; j <= 10; j++)
      if(!(i % j))
        count++;

    if( count == 10 )
      num = i;
  }

  printf("%d\n",num);
}
```

and I get the desirable output for this problem. But whenever I write this code for finding the value which is divisible by 1-20 without any remainder then I didn't find any output. I wrote the below code and compile and run but it didn't give me any result. But the programme is still running and whenever I press <kbd>Control+C</kbd> then the program is terminated.

The code for the problem.....

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  long long int i,j,count = 0,num;

  for (i = 1; count != 20; i++) {
     count = 0;

     for (j = 1; j <= 20; j++)
       if (!( i % j))
         count++;

     if (count == 20)
       num = i;
  }

  printf("%lld\n",num);
}
```

So where is the problem?

Comment: Maybe because it just takes much much much longer to iterate to that number? The number in question is `232792560`, which means that the number of outer cycle iterations will increase by the factor of `92378`. On top of that each iteration takes twice as long. You decided to use a "literal" dumb brute-force approach to solving this problem. So, this is the price to pay.

Comment: And please, post real code. Your second code sample does not even compile due to non-balanced `{}`.

Comment: However, I have to admit that my optimized build of your code found the answer in ~1 minute. Are you building your code with optimizations enabled?

Comment: To get a performant algorithm, you're likely to need to use LCM (least common multiple) and GCD (greatest common divisor), rather than the quadratic code you're currently using.

Comment: This is probably not the fastest solution, but you can optimise a whole lot by realising that divisable by 20 also means divisible by 2, 4, 5  and 10.

Comment: On an ordinary MacBook Pro, a version of the algorithm computed each the values for each the limits of 1 to 20 and printed the results in less than 10 milliseconds (according to `time lcm20`, where `lcm20` is the program I wrote to do the job).  It gives you a benchmark to aim for.  Watch out for arithmetic overflow.

Answer (score 2):

If I were going to do this, I'd do it somewhat differently. Let's start by thinking about a number that isn't the smallest, but is obviously correct otherwise, and really easy to compute: if you simply multiply 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 * 6 * ... N, you get a number that's clearly divisible by all of those smaller numbers.

Now, the question is how we can generate a *smaller* number with the same basic characteristic of being divisible by all the smaller number. We can do that by observing that (for example) 10 factors to 2 * 2 * 5, so (for example) we don't have to separately multiply by 2, 4 or 5 to get a result that's divisible by 2, 4 and 5.

So, we can take our list of numbers, and the prime factorization of each:

```
10: 2 * 2 * 5
9:  3 * 3
8:  2 * 2 * 2
7:  7
6:  2 * 3
5:  5
4:  2 * 2
3:  3
2:  2
1:  1
```

Then we can cross out factors later in the list that appear earlier in the list (but only up to as many times as they appear earlier in the list). That gives us something like this:

```
10: 2 * 2 * 5
9:  3 * 3
8:  2
7:  7
6:  -
5:  -
4:  -
3:  -
2:  -
```

Multiply together what's left (2 * 2 * 5 * 3 * 3 * 2 * 7) and we get the 2520 we expect.

Applying the same technique to 20, we get a list like: `20 19 9 17 4 7 13 11`. Multiplying that out, we get `232792560`.

If you care more about efficiency, you can (for example) use Euclid's algorithm to compute the GCD of a pair of numbers. What we're computing here is the LCM of a pair of numbers, which is the product of the numbers divided by their GCD. We can then repeat using our previous LCM as one of the inputs to the GCD, so we end up with code something like this:

```
unsigned LCM = max;

for (int i = max - 1; i > 1; i--)
    LCM = i * LCM / GCD(i, LCM);
```

There are quite a few ways to compute the GCD as well. A simple, well-known and fairly efficient one is Euclid's algorithm, which looks something like this:

```
unsigned GCD(unsigned u, unsigned v) {
    while ( v != 0) {
        unsigned r = u % v;
        u = v;
        v = r;
    }
    return u;
}
```

Using this, computing the LCM of 1..N for every N from 5 to 30 (and writing them to a file) takes about 3 ms on the machine I'm using at the moment (though I suspect more careful timing would prove it was really faster than that).